# SUM UP COLUMN + DATA in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, where-clause

I am trying to  sum up the column "date_to" with a fix value 432000

I tried without the SUM() function by just date_to+432000 and the result return was not what I expect too.

```
select * 
  from meeting 
 where date_from < 1546272001 
   AND SUM(date_to + 432000) > 1546272001 
   AND account_id > 0
```

ERROR 1111 (HY000): Invalid use of group function

Comment: Incidentally, it's smarter to subtract the constants.

Comment: May be you need to use the the below query instead:

select * 
  from meeting 
 where date_from < 1546272001 
   AND (date_to + 432000) > 1546272001 
   AND account_id > 0;